# Tab Bar Controller interfering with navigation bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbaritem

I am using a Tab Bar Controller with 4 navigation controllers further attached to it,Before starting the project I made a demo and it was working fine. Now the problem is,

1.First cell of tableview is underlapping navigation bar and the navigation bar image is stretched.

2.After I pull the tableview down it comes to normal position but the image issue still persists.

3.The constraints are properly set so no issues there.

what I can do to fix the issue and Explain me in details of the issues?

Comment: Can you share a image of constraints of 1st screen which has tableview?

Comment: @DarshanKarekar [sure here](https://imgur.com/a/KLbtuDg)

Answer (score 0):

If you embed the ViewController the with Navigation Controller then you may face such issues. And if you want to hide the navigation Bar you can implement the following code in viewDidLoad().

`self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)`

Please provide screenshot for better understanding.Thanks

Comment: I think he has provided the screen shots. Please check the links in the question

Comment: I did and if you mean screenshot of storyboard, [here you go](https://imgur.com/a/XdKTmza)

Answer (score 0):

For your first issue try Unchecking

> Adjust Scroll View Insets

[image]